# Running Ubuntu 21.04, the snap version of bitcoin core just shows an empty window with no borders at startup

Tags: snap, 21.04, bitcoin

I just got me the SSD space to run a full node, so I figured I might swith from electrum to bitcoin core.

I installed it as a snap, but when I run it, there is just a huge window titled "Welcome popping up that stratches over my screen size and seems to have no borders at the bottom or the sides, it just expands indefinit.

Any idea what causes that issue?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some problems I had with an HDD being recognized having the wrong capacity. That seems to have fixed the issue